# how to set only one div in right and others with lines in display flex

Tags: html, css

I have this page and I want to set only the first div to be like a right navigation bar and the other on the left with line brakes.

**What I am getting now** : 
[image]

**What I want to achieve** : 
[image]

```html
<div class="flex-div">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
</div>
```

```
.flex-div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: can't we use any other pure css methods? I mean do you really want that using FLEX???

Comment: @iimah9 I missread your question before, but I did change it so it reflects what you need. If you can accept the best answer for you it would be great. 

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your end result that you want to achieve, I'd suggest using **justify-content: flex-end** as it keeps the **no1 closer to the 2, 3, 4.**

```
.flex-div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<style>
.flex-div {    
    display: block;
    justify-content: space-between;
    max-width:50%;
}
.div1and2 {
    display: block;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    text-align:right;
}

.div3and4 {
    display: block;
    justify-content: space-between;
    max-width:100%;
    text-align:right;
}
```

```
<div class="flex-div">
    <div class="div1and2">1</div>
    <div class="div1and2">2</div>
    <div class="div3and4">3</div>
    <div class="div3and4">4</div>
</div>
```

1. "div1and2" class is for first and second div.
2. "div3and4" class is for third and fourth div.
3. Change your display style to block instead of flex.

Answer (score -1):

you can write like below

```css
.flex-div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-div">
    
    <div>1</div>
    <div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Cleaniest way is with `flex-grow` in my opinion. When specifiying this rule, it will take all the space available therefore pushing every sibling divs at the end of the flex container.

After that, you can specify a `width` to the navigation for templating your page.

> flex-grow defines the ability for a flex item to grow if necessary. It accepts a unitless value that serves as a proportion. It dictates what amount of the available space inside the flex container the item should take up.
>
>  
>  For example, if all items have flex-grow set to 1, every child will set to an equal size inside the container. If you were to give one of the children a value of 2, that child would take up twice as much space as the others.

You can read more on flex-grow property on [CSS-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-grow/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

#content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#navigation {
  width: 200px;
}

#navigation, #content div {
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="navigation">1</div>
  <div id="content">
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```css
.flex-div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.left-section{
    background-color:red;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 20px;
}

.right-section{
    background-color:yellow;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-div">
    <div class="left-section">
      <div>1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-section">
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```